# How To Capture Image on volume hardware buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, avcapturesession

I use this notification to catch pressing on volume hardware buttons:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("volumeChanged:"), name: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification", object: nil)
```

Notification is catch but volume indicator is shown in middle of the screen.Before iOS 9.2 was blocked by the notification, now is showing again. Is there any way to block that again

Thanks